# Login page in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Whenever i am creating a login page with oracle db and when the data from db looks for the credential and if it is not found on first place then it prints not found and again i goes similarly until data is found.

```
while(rs.next()) { String id=rs.getString(3);
   String password=rs.getString(4); 
   if(id.equals(uname) && password.equals(psw)) { 
      out.println("Found"); 
      HttpSession session=request.getSession();
      session.setAttribute("Userid", id); 
      response.sendRedirect("home.html"); break; 
   } else if(id!=uname && password!=psw){ 
      out.println("Sorry Username & Password not validated"); 
      break; 
   }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? Could it help to share some code?

Comment: I've edited the question with code you pasted in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `else if` statement 
and for sign in , you need to query unique fields like **email** for example

```
select * from usersTable where email = 'USERINPUT' and password = 'USERINPUT';
```

This query will grab one row result from table and you can use `if` instead of while .

**NOTE :** there should be one row resulted from sign in query

```
if (rs.next()){
   // get your data
}
```